# Where can I find statistics about micronutrients deficiencies in European countries?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, deficiency

[Data from the USDA](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=15672) show that many US residents fail to meet adequate intakes -based on average requirement- of several micronutrients.

For example only 8% of US citizens meet requirements for fiber, 7.6% for potassium, and 43% for magnesium, 51% for vitamin C and 13.6% for vitamin E.

Where can I find similar statistics for european countries?

Comment: As it stands, I think this is a good question in theory, but very broad in practice. Also, if you could summarize the key points from the link, that will help rather than just saying "data shows".

Comment: It's really annoying to be downvoted and put on hold when you can help me to improve the question just by adding some comment as JohnP did. Followin his suggestions I modified the question and now it's very specific, and also includes some key points.

Comment: There could be many issues of a question that take too much time for one person to list at the moment, so putting it on hold is a way of drawing attention to help fix it. Also, people sometimes think that when they downvote, that's enough to make the asker fix their question. For some it's enough, but it can differ based on asker's experience.

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate data sets about nutrient intake of european population are linked to basically two sources:

1. The **EPIC** cohort study, involving more than half a million participants recruited across 10 European countries and followed for almost 15 years. The homepage of the project is http://epic.iarc.fr . There's not a unified table providing summarized statistics for all nutrients as I was asking in my question, but very reliable data can be extracted from individual studies that investigate singular nutrients; the list of these studies can be found here: http://www.nature.com/ejcn/journal/v63/n4s/index.html
2. The **European Nutrition and Health Report**, 2009, showing similar statistics, togheter with other health and lifestyle indicators and major critical issues in each country. The report is here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20081327